# Clear app-data in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I delete all files in app-data. and config again the starting page.all things are 
correct, such as create tables. but when I go to the Module page, I didn't 
see my module. probably Orchard don't recognize 
my module. 

why?

thanks a lot for response

Comment: Does the module compile? Is there a module.txt? Does the module project name match the folder it's in?

Comment: @devqon: Hi devqon... yes, before deleting the app-data my module work it, but after resetting Orchard don't recognize my module!

Comment: Deleting the App_Data folder shouldn't influence the visibility of the module, I do that all the time. Maybe you changed some of the stuff devqon mentioned after the module was registered so that the module itself works but module detection doesn't? Take a look at the logs (App_Data/Logs), there may be something of interest.